# Javascript makes a Get Request to a website and get all paragraphs elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native

I've been working React Native that I need to get all paragraphs elements from a website and then put them in an array and then show in then in Text elements.
I was thinking about web scraping but it seems kind of an overkill,
So I wanted to know with someone has a better solution in mind about it.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does web scraping have to do with react?

Comment: Not exactly web scraping but I wanted to be able to get all paragraphs from a website and then be able to show in a mobile app

Comment: I think the part of that description that is confusing is "from a website".  Your website?  An external website?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm kinda new to programming outside of the normal web. Some concepts are somewhat new to me.

Comment: external website

Comment: So first off, that is a slightly odd desire, because react is meant to be used to build your own frontend, not grab off site markup and use it.  Secondly, that is potentially a legal concern, because if you are grabbing someone elses markup and presenting it as your own, there are potential copyright issues there.

Comment: I understand. But is just for a websites that are free for being for the public that kind be analyzed by third parties, nothing that could give me potential legal issues.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the exact structure of the DOM tree!

Converting DOM elements to array is pretty much easy and meaningful when you do web scraping.

Comment: Okay, I will go for web scraping with Puppeteer. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you cannot use it inside React Native

Comment: You say this because it is a headless browser?
So I can't load a mobile device, what would you recommend?

Comment: Using a headless browser is too much for your use-case. I'd suggest you to look into https://github.com/g6ling/react-native-html-parser